# Create array with image tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have api request which is string data type. It contains random plain text and img tag/ tags all combined all together.  A string can have one or more img tags. I am looking the best way to slice those img tags from rest of the string and put it in an array.

```
"Random text <img src='img-one-src'  alt='alt-one' /> some other random text <img src='img-two-src' src='alt-two' />"
```

The array can be:

```
var imgs = [{src: 'img-one-src', alt: 'alt-one'}, {src: 'img-two-src', alt: 'alt-two'}]
```

Comment: Did you tried to use regex to capture string beginning from "<img" and closing by "/>" ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting a specific error message? If you need guidance on how to ask, please check out this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Create an element and make your string the `innerHTML` of that element. Then use `querySelectorAll('img')` on that element, and drag the result into an array using array spread `[...res]`. If instead of the elements you want the HTML strings in your array, simply use `map()`:

```js
const str ="Random text <img src='img-one-src' /> some other random text <img src='img-two-src' />";

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;

const images = [...div.querySelectorAll('img')];
const imageStrings = images.map(x=>x.outerHTML);

console.log(images, imageStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for doing that.

```js
let str = "Random text <img src='img-one-src' /> some other random text <img src='img-two-src' />";
console.log(str.match(/<img.+?\/>/g));
console.log(str.replace(/<img.+?\/>/g, ""));
```